# How to create app bar with React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm new with React Native and I want to create an app using a shared "app bar" component without changes between views. I create it component but in transition view this also change. E.g:

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: With "app bar", you mean the navigator? You can have a single page with the app bar. Then you just change the other parts of the page by rendering on specific views.

Comment: This looks like a Toolbar in Android. Are you targeting Android or iOS or both?

Comment: Hi, yes, my target is Android and iOS but in this moment I'm focused on Android.